# Can I add a Top 1% list to the Careers 2.0 page?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I have more than a screenful of top 10% tags, and turning them all is a bit tedious.  Can we have a top 1% or top 0.1% to cut the list down a bit.  I am in the top 10 (not 10%) for a few of them.

Comment: Agreed. 10% seems a bit broad.

Comment: @JoshC IMHO 10% is good for most people, but if you are particularly active on StackOverflow, you should be able to demonstrate this. esp if you want to show you have specific or special interests.

Comment: Can't you remove tags individually so they're not displayed?

Comment: Why not just list tags in descending order by top participant percentage and then take the top X tags.  Perhaps with some weighting to remove or lower tags that are simply attached to very few questions.

Comment: @ben there is about a hundred or so of them and you can only show about 5 so I got bored after about 50 of them

Comment: @servy better prioritisation would help. It picks the more popular tags rather than the ones I would like to be known for. The first tag is c# but I have never worked with it.

Comment: Surely 10% will be enough for everyone!